# Why is Get-WinEvent slower than Get-EventLog when getting events after a date?

Tags: powershell

When retrieving events after a specific date Get-WinEvent seems to be slower than Get-EventLog:

```
$SourceComputer = "MyServer"
$LogName = "Security"
$StartDate = (get-date).AddMinutes(-30)
$hashquery = @{logname=$LogName; StartTime=$StartDate}
(Measure-Command -Expression {Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $SourceComputer -FilterHashTable $hashquery}).TotalSeconds
(Measure-Command -Expression {Get-EventLog -Computer $SourceComputer -LogName $Logname -After $StartDate}).TotalSeconds
```

Output:

```
Get-WinEvent: 128.8475308
Get-EventLog: 4.5299092
```

This seems odd since Get-WinEvent is supposed to perform better that the older Get-EventLog function. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I find that Get-WinEvent is only slow querying remote computers. In my scripts, I'm running Get-WinEvent locally on each computer using PSRemoting/Invoke-Command, which performs well. It's much clunkier to turn that into a parallel workflow, but it's doable.

Answer (score 2):

> ...Get-WinEvent is supposed to perform better that the older
>   Get-EventLog...

With most parameters, this is correct. `Get-WinEvent` is faster than `Get-EventLog`, because `Get-EventLog` grabs the *entire* EventLog, then locally filters.

However, `Get-WinEvent` does have a few caveats, the first being `-FilterHashtable` which has a [few](http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/422072/get-winevent-on-vista-does-not-with-vista-x64-using-ctp3) [bugs](http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/689962/powershell-filterhashtable-on-windows-server-2008-rtm).

The second being that `-FilterHashtable` is very slow as per the bottom of the [blog post](http://www.mcbsys.com/techblog/2011/04/powershell-get-winevent-vs-get-eventlog/) cited by Ansgar Wiechers. The recommendation is to use `-FilterXML`

Comment: I get very similar results regardless if I use Hashtable, XML or no filter. Querying the Security event log is ~30 times slower than querying any other log I have tried - even in PS4 (haven't tried on ver. 5)

Comment: Queries against the 'Security' Event Log are typically slower due to the number of events in a given timeframe.  With recommended security-settings, there is an order of magnitude more captured in the 'Security' log versus the 'System', 'Application', or 'Setup' logs.

Comment: In the tests I've made, the different logs were of comparable sizes. Also, the query time was somewhat proportional to the size. But when querying the Security event log, query time was ~30 times longer.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this blog post](http://www.mcbsys.com/techblog/2011/04/powershell-get-winevent-vs-get-eventlog/), `Get-EventLog` seems to be significantly slower when used against remote hosts.

Comment: Yep.. that's what I was expecting, but it's not the case. I get the same behavior whether I run locally or on a remote server.