# Event Log query with Get-WinEvent / Get-EventLog is very slow when querying shutdown event 1074

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm writing a PowerShell script that needs to be able to get the query the `System` Event Log and find events with the [Event ID 1074](http://www.eventid.net/display-eventid-1074-source-USER32-eventno-1783-phase-1.htm) which indicates a shutdown.

To do this, I was using the following code, however, I've taken notice that when running the code on servers with larger `System` Event Logs, the command takes many seconds to complete.

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName 'System' | Where-Object { $_.Id -eq 1074 }
```

Is there a way to improve the performance of this code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Get-WinEvent vs Get-EventLog

The first performance boost you can get is using `Get-WinEvent` over `Get-EventLog`.  That is because `Get-WinEvent` is replacing `Get-EventLog` and [is supposed to perform better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16731635/why-is-get-winevent-slower-than-get-eventlog-when-getting-events-after-a-date).

## Correctly filtering the query

I found a [fantastic article by Ed Wilson](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/how-to-improve-the-performance-of-a-powershell-event-log-query/) which goes into great detail how you can improve the performance of a query such as the one I've posted above.  I will highlight the performance tweaks I made to greatly improve the performance of my script.

1. Don't use the `-LogName` parameter, but rather, use the appropriate `-ProviderName` of the provider that generates the event you're looking for (Ed's blog post goes into detail of how to find this).  In my case, I needed to use the `User32` provider since that's the provider that generates the `1074` event I'm interested in.
2. Avoid full traversals of data if at all possible.  You'll notice my script had a `Where-Object` clause.  This clause would iterate over ever event piped into it looking for only the ones that have the `1074` Id.  To avoid this, Get-WinEvent has a [`-FilterHashtable` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/Creating-Get-WinEvent-queries-with-FilterHashtable?view=powershell-7) which can be used to filter your query results within the `Get-WinEvent` cmdlet, improving efficiency.  As quoted in the Microsoft documentation: ***"When you work with large event logs, it's not efficient to send objects down the pipeline to a Where-Object command."***

## The code

I've implemented the aforementioned concepts and timed the improvements for each to show the difference in performance using the `Measure-Command` cmdlet with the `-Expression` parameter.  Note that the machine that I'm testing on has 23,581 events in the `System` log.

### Baseline

```
Measure-Command -Expression {
    Get-WinEvent -LogName 'System' | Where-Object { $_.Id -eq 1074 }
}

# TotalSeconds      : 7.600536
```

### Using `ProviderName` vs `LogName`

```
Measure-Command -Expression {
    Get-WinEvent -ProviderName 'User32' | Where-Object { $_.Id -eq 1074 }
}

# TotalSeconds      : 0.1929325
```

### Using `FilterHashtable`

```
Measure-Command -Expression {
    Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{ProviderName = "User32"; Id = 1074} 
}

# TotalSeconds      : 0.1578928
```

Comment: Great find! (+1) for this!

Comment: Great post.  I get a faster result with the logname in the filterhashtable.  `measure-command { get-winevent @{logname = 'system'; id = 1074} } | % totalseconds`.  Note that there's a 256 limit in the windows api with the number of lognames.  Searching all the logs requires a foreach loop.  The event viewer has this same limitation with views.