# Get-WinEvent slower than Get-EventLog

Tags: windows, powershell, events

Get-Winevent is 10 times slower than Get-EventLog

I've read
[text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60601715/event-log-query-with-get-winevent-get-eventlog-is-very-slow-when-querying-shut)
and
[text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16731635/why-is-get-winevent-slower-than-get-eventlog-when-getting-events-after-a-date)

But I dont get the point.

I'm using Providername and don't FilterHashtable.

```
Measure-Command -Expression {
    $events = Get-WinEvent -ProviderName Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing -MaxEvents 1000  | Where-Object { $logids.Keys -contains $_.ID }
}
#
```

vs.

```
Measure-Command -Expression {
    $events = Get-EventLog -LogName Security -Newest 1000| Where-Object { $logids.Keys -contains $_.EventID }
}
#
```

gives 25 seconds for the Get-WinEvent vs. 2,8 seconds for Get-EventLog

Comment: for starters for a fair performance test, `$logids` should be inside the scriptblock of `Measure-Command`. Also the output type of these cmdlets is different and the formatting is also different.

Comment: Sorry, It tried this, but it doesn't change the result: